# Is the mounting point of a file system not a hard link?

Tags: mount, hard-disk

Correct me if I am wrong: A hard link can't link to a file on a different filesystem, because the hard link's entry in the hardlink's parent directory can't point to an inode in a different filesystem than the file system of the hardlink's parent directory.

A filesystem can be mounted under a directory in a different filesystem.  Does that mean the filesystem's mounting point isn't a hard link, based on my understanding about hardlinks?

Comment: All directory entries are either hard links or symbolic links; the directory entry doesn't store anything else.  A bit of poking around shows that the inode number of a filesystem's mount point is either 1 or 2 on all filesystems I have.  Obviously those are inode numbers on the filesystem that is mounted at that mount point—not the same as the inode number of the directory once that filesystem is unmounted.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post your commands and outputs?